# Can API Platform be deployed in a LAMP env' on shared hosting, like Hostgator?

Tags: deployment, lamp, api-platform.com

I currently have a reseller account through Hostgator and am wondering if API Platform can be deployed there. The documentation states "The server part of API Platform is basically a standard Symfony application, that you can also easily deploy on your own servers." but it's not clear to me whether or not the server part (e.g., /api) can be broken out of Docker and installed in a standard LAMP lamp env. It seems feasible but I'm not certain it would work like that.

Any guidance will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can! The Docker integration is 100% optional.
Because the content of this directory is actually just the Symfony Skeleton + the configuration for the API Platform bundle, you can just upload the content of the api/ directory on any LAMP server. Set the appropriate environment variables (for instance the RDBMS), and you’re done.

Comment: I have actually read more through the documentation and was about to answer my own question when I saw ya beat me to it. Thanks, Kevin :) And thanks for all the work you and your team have put into this beautiful project; I look forward to using it!